# Search group of numbers in int array without using a loop

Tags: java, search, integer

I have the following array

`int[] a = { 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3 };`

i would like to search the array for the flat sequences,
and return the longest flat sequence in the array.

for this array the answer would be 3 (5,6,5)

is there a way to do it without using a loop?

Comment: if you don't want to use loop you should go for recursion

Comment: Looks like a homework question. Did you try to find basic information regarding your assignment and did try to approach it yourself? There's a lot of information about recursion on the internet, nothing should stop you from making an attempt if you want to lean. Please see [*Open letter to students with homework problems*](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can use recursion but that doesn't *really* gets rid of a loop. You just dont write the keyword `while` or `for`

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3 };
        System.out.println(sequenceRecursive(a, 0, 0, 0));
    }

    public static int sequenceRecursive(int[] arr, int startIndex, int longest, int sequence) {
        if(startIndex <= 0) startIndex = 1;
        if(startIndex >= arr.length) return longest + 1;
        if(arr[startIndex] > arr[startIndex - 1]){
            sequence++;
            if(sequence > longest) longest = sequence;
        }else{
            sequence = 0;
        }
        return sequenceRecursive(arr, ++startIndex, longest, sequence);
    }
```

Comment: That works perfectly fine according to the assignment,
but im required to only input the array like so for example  (longestFlatSequence (int[] arr))
is there a way to divide what you did?

Comment: Thats not possible. Is your assignment also saying that you can`t use a loop?

Comment: i just used override. thx alot :)